# JavaScript version of this jQuery line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for a javascript alternative for the following code:

```
$('a[href*="vivo.sx/"]').attr('href')
```

I have never worked with javascript. This may be very simple for someone who's more experienced with javascript.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: nice page but i get "Your search didn't match any comparisons."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a version that does it both way for comparison..

Please note I've used document.querySelector, not document.querySelectorAll, if you use the All variant, remember you need to loop the result.

```js
console.log( $('a[href*="vivo.sx/"]').attr('href') );
console.log( document.querySelector('a[href*="vivo.sx/"]').href );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.vivo.sx/tester">one</a>
```